# Custom shaped container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

Can anyone help me draw this kind of custom shape in flutter? Or provide me with relevant resources that will clarify my query related to custom shapes in flutter.

[image]

Some code or hint that will be guide me.

Comment: Use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package, Try to refer [RoundedDiagonalPathClipper Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers#:~:text=ClipPath(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clipper%3A%20RoundedDiagonalPathClipper,%22RoundedDiagonalPathClipper()%22))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%2C)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try The following:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(

      body: SafeArea(
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: Clippy(),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: 500,
          height:500 ,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.purple,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the clipper

```
class Clippy extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    
    Path path = new Path();

    double w = size.width;
    double h = size.height;

    path.lineTo(0,0.55*h);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(7, (0.75*h)+20 ,60 ,(0.75*h)+30);
    path.lineTo(w+50 , h);
    path.lineTo(w,0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
  return  false;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

one more thing, i noticed a red button **challenges**, don't go straight for painters or clippers.

Figure out whether it can be done with Transformation operations like skew or something.